# Pine Script - request.security_lower_tf

Tags: pine-script

looking to see the stochastic of a lower TF to get a better entry < with a view to creating an alert to telegram>.
Have used the pine script v5 manual for guidance <request.security_lower_tf >. When I use a chart on a daily and place the code to look a the 15min stochastic chart. It does not corelate with a chart based on 15min and using the stochastic based on this chart for the same pair.

when I change to a daily or weekly chart the stoch based on 15min changes. So I seem not be accessing the lower timeframe data. I can understand if I was using an hourly chart, because possibly I could only be getting 4 bars worth of data of 15min. But if this was the case would expect the 15min stoch. on a weekly/monthly chart not to change.

Also the scale seems to wrong across different time periods
Code:

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="Stochastic LWR TImeframe", shorttitle="Stoch", format=format.price, precision=2)

string i_Period = input.timeframe(title="Lower Timeframe", defval="15")
periodK = input.int(14, title="%K Length", minval=1)
smoothK = input.int(1, title="%K Smoothing", minval=1)
periodD = input.int(3, title="%D Smoothing", minval=1)



//GET STOCHASTIC VALUES 
float k = ta.sma(ta.stoch(close, high, low, periodK), smoothK)
float d = ta.sma(k,periodD)

// Get lower timeframe values
float[] LTF_k = request.security_lower_tf(syminfo.tickerid, i_Period, k)
float LTF_k1 = nz(array.sum(LTF_k) /k)
float[] LTF_d = request.security_lower_tf(syminfo.tickerid, i_Period, d)
float LTF_d1 = nz(array.sum(LTF_d) /d)

      

//PLOT
plot(LTF_k1, title="%K", color=#2962FF)
plot(LTF_d1, title="%D", color=#FF6D00)
h0 = hline(80, "Upper Band", color=#787B86)
hline(50, "Middle Band", color=color.new(#787B86, 50))
h1 = hline(20, "Lower Band", color=#787B86)
fill(h0, h1, color=color.rgb(33, 150, 243, 90), title="Background")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your stoch calculation is off. Just do it as you would do on your chart's timeframe and then pass the `k` and `d` to `security()`.

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="Stochastic LWR TImeframe", shorttitle="Stoch", format=format.price, precision=2)

string i_Period = input.timeframe(title="Lower Timeframe", defval="15")
periodK = input.int(14, title="%K Length", minval=1)
smoothK = input.int(1, title="%K Smoothing", minval=1)
periodD = input.int(3, title="%D Smoothing", minval=1)

ctf_k = ta.sma(ta.stoch(close, high, low, periodK), smoothK)
ctf_d = ta.sma(ctf_k, periodD)

[_ltf_k, _ltf_d] = request.security_lower_tf(syminfo.tickerid, i_Period, [ctf_k, ctf_d])

len = array.size(_ltf_k)

float ltf_k = (len > 0) ? array.get(_ltf_k, len - 1) : na
float ltf_d = (len > 0) ? array.get(_ltf_d, len - 1) : na

//PLOT
plot(ltf_k, title="%K", color=#2962FF)
plot(ltf_d, title="%D", color=#FF6D00)
h0 = hline(80, "Upper Band", color=#787B86)
hline(50, "Middle Band", color=color.new(#787B86, 50))
h1 = hline(20, "Lower Band", color=#787B86)
fill(h0, h1, color=color.rgb(33, 150, 243, 90), title="Background")
```